# android studio 2.2 preview app cannot recognize library dependencies

Tags: android, dependencies, android-studio-2.2

i have a project with library project,third dependencies in library project:

library build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'

  compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

  compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
  compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
  compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
  compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.1'

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

  //compile project(':library')
  debugCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'debug')
  releaseCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release')
}
```

now i got a problem,which is i can't use dependencies class in library.somewhat it din't recognize these libs.

[image]

but when i put dependencies to app build.grandle. this problem gone.
so could anybody help me? what's the problem.

thanks!

Comment: Try adding `include ':library'` in you `settings.gradle` file, assuming you don't already have it.

Comment: @leeo Have you sold the problem? I've faced the same

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  2 of my dependency libraries have jar files in them that are being ignored by the main app.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the transitive dependency with the gradle try setting that to true.

in the app build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

  //compile project(':library')
  debugCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'debug'){transitive = true}
  releaseCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release'){transitive = true}
}
```

Just a wild guess completely not sure but worth a try.